# When is the firebase_campaign event triggered?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en states in passing that `firebase_campaign` is auto-generated. Unfortunately ‘[Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485)’ doesn’t document that particular event. When is it triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebase_campaign* event is automatically triggered by user interaction and is not intended to be shown on the Firebase console. The data corresponding to event in form of the parameters is passed to Ads framework for further analysis and generating quality content.

The only way to obtain the data related to that event is via the [Big Query export](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512).

Comment: I am using Bigquery. 'user interaction' is rather broad -- do you have any more specific info?

Comment: Clicking an ad or clicking campaign URL generated by Google Play URL builder tool, essentially carrying source, medium, campaign parameters something similar to this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#CAMPAIGN_DETAILS